# Is there a way to export Scala case class into d.ts (TypeScript)

Tags: scala, typescript, case-class

I want to take Scala Case Classes and export it into a d.ts ([TypeScript definition](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files)) file. is it possible? If so, What's the best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Even if there were, TypeScript could do nothing with it, since it would not have an actual JavaScript implementation of that class.

Comment: I don't need implementation. I just want to get the classes structure

Comment: Yes it's possible. Can you share what you have tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: I have to experience with Scala, and I just want to do a POC on that. can you give me a simple example? that will do!

Comment: @gilamran What does POC stand for?

Comment: It's been a long time, but maybe with one of these libs you can solve, I'm with sbt 1.1.1 and I had no luck [SCALA-TSI](https://github.com/code-star/scala-tsi) [SCALA-TS](https://github.com/miloszpp/scala-ts) [Swagger Generator, for Api-Rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ts-generator)

Comment: A major version of [Scala-TS](https://scala-ts.github.io/scala-ts/) has been recently released (I'm a contributor of)